# If we know the size of Jordan blocks of a matrix, what else can we derive?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

If we have a 4x4 matrix with **two distinct eigenvalues** and if all Jordan blocks are of size **1x1**, can we say that the matrix must be **diagonal**?

I am struggling to correlate the number non-diagonal elements with Jordan block sizes. Diagonal matrix is an option; but, are there any other possibility? What can we say about the matrix?

Comment: Saying "if all Jordan blocks are of size $1$" is saying that the matrix is diagonal, or not? But this need not be the case. We can also have two blocks of size $2$, or one block of size $2$ and two of size $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you are right, I was a bit confused, sorry about that. If we have one 2x2 Jordan block and three 1x1 Jordan blocks, is it possible to say we have only 1 off-diagonal element?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (ever, unless the Jordan form is a scalar multiple of the identity, in which case it is *equal to* the matrix) conclude from the Jordan form whether a square matrix is diagonal. The best thing you might deduce from the Jordan is that the matrix is *diagonalisable*, which means precisely that all Jordan blocks are $1\times1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: you are right, I'll replace the exception condition by being scalar, which is the right one.